# What should I know before poking around an unknown archive file for things?

Tags: file-format

A game that I play stores all of its data in a .DAT file. There has been [some work](http://wiki.xentax.com/index.php?title=Guild_Wars_DAT) done by people in examining the file. There are also some [existing tools](http://wiki.xentax.com/index.php?title=Game_Tools#Guild_Wars), but I'm not sure about their current state. I think it would be fun to poke around in the data myself, but I've never tried to examine a file, much less anything like this before.

Is there anything I should know about examining a file format for data extraction purposes before I dive headfirst into this?

EDIT: I would like very general tips, as examining file formats seems interesting. I would like to be able to take File X and learn how to approach the problem of learning about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. You'll definitely want a hex editor before you get too far.  It will let you see the raw data as numbers instead of as large empty blocks in whatever font notepad is using (or whatever text editor).
2. Try opening it in any archive extractors you have (i.e. zip, 7z, rar, gz, tar etc.) to see if it's just a renamed file format (.PK3 is something like that).
3. Look for headers of known file formats somewhere within the file, which will help you discover where certain parts of the data are stored (i.e. do a search for "IPNG" to find any (uncompressed) png files somewhere within).
4. If you do find where a certain piece of data is stored, take a note of its location and length, and see if you can find numbers equal to either of those values near the beginning of the file, which usually act as pointers to the actual data.
5. Some times you just have to guess, or intuit what a certain value means, and if you're wrong, well, keep moving.  There's not much you can do about it.
6. I have found that http://www.wotsit.org is particularly useful for known file type formats, for help finding headers within the .dat file.

Answer (score 3):

Back up the file first. Once you've restricted the amount of damage you can do, just poke around as Ed suggested.

Comment: I should have mentioned backing up in my question. It would probably rank among the "stupidest things to do" if you poked around a file without a backup of the original. Especially if you have no idea what is going on.

Comment: :) Sorry. I realize it's obvious, but even people who have been in the computer industry for years occasionally forget. Its helpful to see a reminder every now and then. Good luck with your reverse engineering!

Comment: Granted, but it still happens on a daily basis.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your rep level, I guess a basic primer on hexadecimal numbers, endianness, representations for various data types, and all that would be a bit superfluous. A good tool that can show the data in hex is of course essential, as is the ability to write quick scripts to test complex assumptions about the data's structure. All of these should be obvious to you, but might perhaps help someone else so I thought I'd mention them.

Answer (score 3):

One of the best ways to attack unknown file formats, when you have some control over contents is to take a differential approach. Save a file, make a small and controlled change, and save again. Do a binary compare of the files to find the difference - preferably using a tool that can detect inserts and deletions. If you're dealing with an encrypted file, a small change will trigger a massive difference. If it's just compressed, the difference will not be localized. And if the file format is trivial, a simple change in state will result in a simple change to the file.

Answer (score 3):

The other thing is to look at some of the common compression techniques, notably zip and gzip, and learn their "signatures". Most of these formats are "self identifying" so when they start decompressing, they can do quick sanity checks that what they're working on is in a format they understand.

Barring encryption, an archive file format is basically some kind of indexing mechanism (a directory or sorts), and a way located those elements from within the archive via pointers in the index.

With the the ubiquitousness of the standard compression algorithms, it's mostly a matter of finding where those blocks start, and trying to hunt down the index, or table of contents.

Some will have the index all in one spot (like a file system does), others will simply precede each element within the archive with its identity information. But in the end somewhere, there is information about offsets from one block to another, there is information about data types (for example, if they're storing GIF files, GIF have a signature as well), etc.

Those are the patterns that you're trying to hunt down within the file.

It would be nice if somehow you can get your hand on two versions of data using the same format. For example, on a game, you might be able to get the initial version off the CD and a newer, patched version. These can really highlight the information you're looking for.